# How to add onclick event to dynamically created radio buttons in MVC 4?

Tags: javascript, css, html, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am trying to build a form dynamically in ASP.NET  MVC 4 and adding radio button controls dynamically to the page as below. Is it possible to add OnClick event to these dynamically generated controls? or is it possible to write a generic JavaScript function that can respond to the click events of any radio button? Appreciate any help with this.

```
<div style="display: inline">
                                    @for (int k = 0; k < Model.SectionInfos[i].QuestionInfos[j].Value.Options.Count; k++)
                                    {
                                        @Html.HiddenFor(model => Model.SectionInfos[i].QuestionInfos[j].Value.Options[k].Id)
                                        @Html.HiddenFor(model => Model.SectionInfos[i].QuestionInfos[j].Value.Options[k].Name)
                                        @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => Model.SectionInfos[i].QuestionInfos[j].Value.PrimaryValue, Model.SectionInfos[i].QuestionInfos[j].Value.Options[k].PrimaryValue, Model.SectionInfos[i].QuestionInfos[j].Value.Options[k].Name) @Model.SectionInfos[i].QuestionInfos[j].Value.Options[k].Name
                                    }
                                </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to put the click event on the document instead of the radio button

```
$(document).on('click', 'RadioButtonSelector', function(){
    //Do something
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. what is 'RadioButtonSelector'?

Comment: if you have a class or an id on your radio button it is what you you to select that radio button # for id and . for class.  from what you have shown your id's are going to be pretty crazy so I would recommend adding a class and using that to select the radio buttons